# React JS hide div while scrolling another div

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am trying to hide one div during scrolling another big scrollable div.
I have tried doing this via jQuery, but I faced several problems working on mobile devices and was told not to use jQuery with React. So I would like to implement this with pure js or css.

I have seen several tutorials but all they use `position: fixed/absolute` parameter and then during scrolling change the position with negative numbers. This doesn't work for me, as I can't use this position pramaeter.

I would like to provide code snippets.
This is div that needs to be hidden.

```
    <div className="heading">
      <h1 className="heading-text">Заклади для вас</h1>
      <div className="filter">{filterIcon}</div>
    </div> 

.heading {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  max-height: 90px;
  max-width: 425px;
  margin: 1em auto 2em auto;
}
```

This div is scrollable

```
   <div className="badges">
     //for instance//
     <p>something</p>
     <p>something</p>
     <p>something</p>
   </div>


.badges {
  max-width: 315px;
  height: 80vh;
  padding: 20px 7% 0px 7%;
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

Have already tried many variants of realization but nothing worked. Hope you will help me.

Answer (score 0):

Have a visibility identifier state for the heading first.

```
const [isVisible, setIsVisible] = useState(true);

{ isVisible && <div className='heading'..../>}
```

Then detect scroll on the target element and set the visibility state to false.

```
const target = document.querySelector('.badges');
  
target.addEventListener("scroll", function(){
  setIsVisible(false)
}, false);
```

**Bonus:** Put the above code inside a useEffect hook